# Navigation falls out of alignment

Tags: html, css, navigation

For some reason when I load the my website the navigation initially appears in the div below, but once you navigate to another page it appears properly aligned (even if you return to the original page). It also works once you've navigated to another tab, but can still break when reloading the index.

Here is the link to my site: http://jjeff2payd.github.io/index.html

Feel free to inspect the code, not sure what the problem is

**EDIT:**
Here is the added code for the navigation portion

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="./profile.html" title="Learn more">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="./experience.html" title="Do things">Experience</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="./blog.html" title="Think less">Blog</a>
  </li>     
  <li>
    <a href="./contact.html" title="Get in touch">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
 .nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 3em;
    padding-top: 6px;
 }
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome 27

Comment: Looks and loads ok on Firefox 21.0

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-top: 50px;` from your class called nav. This will make your site pretty again :)

Comment: I tried this, but I actually need the margin for when it does properly align (such as going to a different page and then returning). Thanks, please let me know if you have any other ideas